# how to transform array of c# primitive type assigned to Object into something I can iterate through?

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to iterate through the fields in an Object (using reflection, via FieldInfo) and dump their values... and just fell headfirst into a C# vs Java trap.

The problem I'm running into is the fact that

1. FieldInfo.GetValue(srcObject) can return an int[] (or some other array of primitive values) as an Object
2. c# doesn't allow you to cast an Object holding an int[] to Object[]

So... if

`System.Object val = fieldInfo.GetValue(srcObject)`

and

`val.GetType().IsArray` returns 'True'

... what do I need to do to

1. Recognize at runtime that 'val' is "an Object that's an array, but not an array of Objects"?
2. transform 'val' into an array of printable values that I **can** iterate through?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast it to `System.Collections.IEnumerable` first, because all arrays are enumerable:

```
    Foo f = new Foo();
    var fieldInfo = typeof(Foo).GetField("field");
    var value = fieldInfo.GetValue(f);
    if (value.GetType().IsArray) {
        var enumerable = (IEnumerable)value;
        foreach (var item in enumerable) {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
```

If you have multi-dimensional arrays and you want to get the length of each dimension, then you can cast to `Array`:

```
    if (value.GetType().IsArray) {
        var array = (Array)value;
```

Then you can call `GetLength`:

```
int firstDimensionLength = array.GetLength(0);
int secondDimensionLength = array.GetLength(1);
```

Comment: Hmmm... one tiny snag... if the IEnumerable ends up being a 2-dimensional array (eg, int[,]), is there any way (via IEnumerable) to discern the row and column of the current element? Or to at least discern (prior to beginning the iteration) how many rows & columns there are, and derive them by maintaining a counter & taking the modulus and remainder of it?

Comment: @Bitbang3r If that's the case, you can cast to `System.Array` instead. Then you can call `GetLength` and pass in the dimension. Actually, now that I think about it, `Array` is a much better type to cast to. Forget about `IEnumerable`.